# Only first embedded svg is visible

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to embed a few svgs into my html code (I don't have access to the source, I can only inject script/css). However, the script only adds the first svg and the others are not visible. If I remove the first svg injection from the code, the 2nd svg becomes visible and so on.

Working example available here:
https://jsfiddle.net/8vupjhqo/

I'm using this method to inject svgs:

```
$(".z_jobad-country .inner").prepend(
   '<span class="z_icon-before"><svg>SVG content</svg></span>'
);
```

How can I ensure that all svgs become visible?

Comment: The problem are the IDs you are duplicating. You got `<clipPath id="clip0">` and `<g clip-path="url(#clip0)"` in each of those SVGs, but IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented – you should **always avoid duplicate IDs.**

### You might not need any clip paths

Unfortunately a lot of applications add **unnecessary clip paths.**

You can usually detect these comparing the svg's `viewBox` or width and height against the clip paths's dimensions:

```
<svg width="31" height="31" >

<clipPath id="clip0">
  <rect x="132" y="440" width="31" height="31" />
</clipPath>
```

There is nothing to clip!

In your case, you could easily circumvent this issue by removing all clip-paths and `clip-path` references.

A simple string find-replace would already do the job:

Find `clip-path="url(#clip0)"` - replace with "".

On this occasion you can also optimize (e.g using [SVOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)) your icons and reduce the file size significantly.

```js
let icon1 = `<svg width="31" height="31" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 31 31">
  <g transform="translate(-132 -440)">
    <path d="M 155.7 454 c 0 3.8 -3.1 6.8 -6.8 6.8 c -3.8 0 -6.8 -3 -6.8 -6.8 c 0 -3.8 3 -6.8 6.8 -6.8 c 3.7 0 6.8 3 6.8 6.8 z m -4.5 6.4 l 0.8 2.2 c -4.8 1.7 -10.1 -0.7 -11.8 -5.5 c -1.7 -4.8 0.8 -10 5.6 -11.7 l 0 0 l 0.8 2.2 m 1 15.8 l 0 2.2 m -3.1 0 l 6 0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.664286" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none" />
  </g>
</svg>`;

$(".z_jobad-country .inner").prepend(`<span class="z_icon-before">${icon1}</span>`);
$(".z_jobad-date .inner").prepend(`<span class="z_icon-before">${icon1}</span>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="z_icongroup">
  <div class="joblayouttoken rtltextaligneligible displayDTM z_jobad-country">
    <div class="inner fontcolora880bb1b" style="font-family:customfa823167445542ab84ab1; font-size:14px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 fontalign-left">
          <span xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" data-careersite-propertyid="customfield3" class="rtltextaligneligible">United States
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="joblayouttoken rtltextaligneligible displayDTM z_jobad-date">
    <div class="inner fontcolora880bb1b" style="font-family:customfa823167445542ab84ab1; font-size:14px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 fontalign-left">
          <span xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" data-careersite-propertyid="date" class="rtltextaligneligible">3 days ago</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```